# Modify the reverse stack method

Tags: java, android, handler, andengine

I have a problem with my method that I use for highlighting monsters (I simply swith sprites) but the problem is, that it doesn't highlight every monster but only the last one added.

here is the method for highlighting:

```
public void highlightMonsters(){
    while (mStack.size()!=0){
        if (mStack.peek().toString().equals("1")) {
            monsterTopLeft.setVisible(!visibility);
            monsterTopLeftColored.setVisible(visibility);
            monsterTopLeftColored.registerUpdateHandler(changeColorsMonster1);
            mReverseStack.push(mStack.pop());
            monsterTopLeft.registerUpdateHandler(cakaj);
        }
        else if(mStack.peek().toString().equals("2")) {
            monsterTopRight.setVisible(!visibility);
            monsterTopRightColored.setVisible(visibility);
            monsterTopRightColored.registerUpdateHandler(changeColorsMonster2);
            mReverseStack.push(mStack.pop());
            monsterTopRight.registerUpdateHandler(cakaj);
        }
        else if(mStack.peek().toString().equals("3")) {
            monsterBottomLeft.setVisible(!visibility);
            monsterBottomLeftColored.setVisible(visibility);
            monsterBottomLeftColored.registerUpdateHandler(changeColorsMonster3);
            mReverseStack.push(mStack.pop());
            monsterBottomLeft.registerUpdateHandler(cakaj);
        }
        else if (mStack.peek().toString().equals("4")){
            monsterBottomRight.setVisible(!visibility);
            monsterBottomRightColored.setVisible(visibility);
            monsterBottomRightColored.registerUpdateHandler(changeColorsMonster4);
            mReverseStack.push(mStack.pop());
            monsterBottomRight.registerUpdateHandler(cakaj);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the main loop

```
public void mainLoop() {

    cislo = generateNumber();
    testText.setText(String.valueOf(cislo));
    mReverseStack.push(new Integer(cislo)); //debugging purposes
    //cisla su v mReverseStack
    reverseNumbersInStack2();
    //prehodime do mStack
    highlightMonsters();
    //vysvietime a zaroven prehodime do mReverseStack
    reverseNumbersInStack2();
    //prehodime do mStack
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if your code is well suited for your purpose, but if you want your code to work, you don't peek, you pop. And that once per loop - doing it in your if-statement potentially causes an endless loop if you not cover a number. Something like this should work, if there is no error in other parts of your code :

```
public void highlightMonsters(){
    while (mStack.size()!=0){ 
      String monsterString = mStack.pop().toString();
        switch(monsterString) 
case "1" : {
            monsterTopLeft.setVisible(!visibility);
            monsterTopLeftColored.setVisible(visibility);
            monsterTopLeftColored.registerUpdateHandler(changeColorsMonster1);
            monsterTopLeft.registerUpdateHandler(cakaj);
            break;
        }
case "2" :  {
            monsterTopRight.setVisible(!visibility);
            monsterTopRightColored.setVisible(visibility);
            monsterTopRightColored.registerUpdateHandler(changeColorsMonster2);
            monsterTopRight.registerUpdateHandler(cakaj);
            break;
        }
case "3" :  {
            monsterBottomLeft.setVisible(!visibility);
            monsterBottomLeftColored.setVisible(visibility);
            monsterBottomLeftColored.registerUpdateHandler(changeColorsMonster3);
            monsterBottomLeft.registerUpdateHandler(cakaj);
            break;
        }
case "4" : (mStack.peek().toString().equals("4")){
            monsterBottomRight.setVisible(!visibility);
            monsterBottomRightColored.setVisible(visibility);
            monsterBottomRightColored.registerUpdateHandler(changeColorsMonster4);
            monsterBottomRight.registerUpdateHandler(cakaj);
            break;
        }
default : break;
    }  
  mReverseStack.push(monsterString);
  } 
}
```

However, I really recommend not using this kind of code. You should try pushing your monsters themself on a stack instead of numbers and make the changeColors-Stuff more generic with parameters. Or, at least put some of the code in the if or case-statements into a seperate method. This redundancy in the code above is no good coding style and you will run into problems sooner or later.

Comment: thanks for the code. I realized that the problem was another handler wasn't there to wait before changing another color

Answer (score 0):

if you want your `while()` cycle decrease your stack, use `pop()` instead of `peek()`

Comment: I use that pop method to transfer the object. the problem is that I need first to check the first object and then highlight and then move it to another stack.

Comment: and what about mStack size in this place: `while (mStack.size()!=0)`? isn't it equals 1?

Comment: that is the condition for moving all the numbers from one stack to another.